# How to Update Values in a Vector Based off Other Columns

Tags: r

I have recently started to learn R and have gotten stuck trying to work through a problem.  I have read in a .csv file which has several different columns which includes `pickup_name` and `pickup_zipcode`.

I am looking to update text for the `pickup_name` if the name is '`Whole Foods`' and `pickup_zipcode = 12345` to be the name '`Whole Foods-H1`' but have not figured out the correct syntax.  I am currently trying to use `gsub()`.  I know if I just wanted to upate values based off the purchaser_name I would simply do:

```
Data_Delivery$pickup_name = gsub("Whole Foods", "Whole Foods-H1",
                                  Data_Delivery$pickup_name,
                                  fixed = TRUE)`
```

But what if I am basing it off of the zipcode as well?  Also, the pickup_zipcode column does have "`NA`" values.  All I am looking to do is if the condition is met, only update text for this pickup_name but leave the other names as they were.  Any help would be beneficial.

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload a sample of the data set? Also, remember to ensure your question is minimal complete and verifiable as highlighted in the link:- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the second condition to your code.

```
cond=which(Data_Delivery$pickup_zipcode==12345)
Data_Delivery$pickup_name[cond] = gsub("Whole Foods", "Whole Foods-H1",
                              Data_Delivery$pickup_name[cond],
                              fixed = TRUE)`
```

Comment: That worked.  However, for some reason instead of my results appearing as "Whole Foods-H1" it's displaying as "<NA>".  Not sure why

Comment: I see this when I check the values for Data_Delivery$pickup_name

Comment: Nevermind. I saw that there were others who hit the same error and when they used "StringAsFactors = FALSE" in their read.csv, it seemed to do the trick.  So I tried it myself, and it worked!!.   Thank you so much for your assistance.